# Regex Finding Correct Decimal Number 1.0 OR 1.99 To 10.0

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a number that is between 1.0 or 1.10 but wont be higher than 10.0

Here is what I have so far,

```
^0$|^[1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}$|^10\.0$
```

this one is working for `1.55` 
I tried adding an [OR](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to the expression, to find eg `1.5` but unfortunately it will not find `1.55` it does however continute to find `1.5`
Here is my attempt at the or statement

```
^0$|^[1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}$|[1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}$^10\.0$
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/tT1dX7/16) is the site that I'm trying this with.

Comment: So is `1.55` a valid number in the range?  If so, then I would suggest not using regex here, just compare values directly in your app language.

Comment: Your range is not clear `1.0` OR `1.99` To `10.0`...
 between `1.0` or `1.10` but wont be higher than `10.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the alternation between `[0-9]{2}$` and `^10`, if you add `|` as your begining regex did, it should work.

```
^0$|^[1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}$|[1-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}$|^10\.0$
```

Besides, `{1}` here is not required, because it's repeated only one time.
This regex is shorter:

```
^0$|^[1-9]\.[0-9]$|[1-9]\.[0-9]{2}$|^10\.0$
```

Comment: Your pattern does not seem to be completely correct, [see here](https://regex101.com/r/9qX6bB/1).

Comment: thank you @TimBiegeleisen, I put | at wrong position, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex that accept only numbers with max 2 decimals:

```
^0$|^[1-9](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$|^10(?:\.00?)?$
```

It will also accept `10.00` and all integers without decimals from `0` to `10`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tT1dX7/19

If you want to add numbers with maximum 2 decimals that are between `0` and `1` to your initial range (`1-10` -> `0-10`)

```
^[0-9](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$|^10(?:\.00?)?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tT1dX7/20

Now if you want to accept more than 2 decimals in your range (`0-10`)

```
^[0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?$|^10(?:\.0+)?$
```

Demo:    https://regex101.com/r/tT1dX7/21

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `^(?:1\.(?:0\d|[1-9]\d)|(?:[2-9]|10)\.00)$`

```
 ^     
 (?:
      #  1.00  -  1.99
      1
      \.
      (?:
           0 \d 
        |  [1-9] \d 
      )
   |  
      #  2.00  -  10.00
      (?:
           [2-9] 
        |  10
      )
      \.00
 )
 $
```